# Redirect to another page on clicking the back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

When a user visits my page and clicks on the back button I want to redirect them to another page. How can I do this? This is in a simple PHP or HTML Web page.

Comment: Sounds annoying, and a dream come true for spammers. Users generally expect the back button to work a certain way, changing that is probably not a good idea. That said, you could check out the History API, and then keep track of viewed pages, and if the user goes back, show them something completely unexpected.

Comment: No one in his sane mind would help you do that. This is something that just should not exist.

Answer (score 0):

if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

```
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      var hashLocation = location.hash;
      var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
      var hashName = hashSplit[1];

      if (hashName !== '') {
        var hash = window.location.hash;

        if (hash === '') {
          alert('Back button was pressed.');
            window.location='https://www.google.com/';
            return false;
        }
      }
    });

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
  }
```

This code works on all updated browsers except internet explorer . For internet explorer JSBBQ library needs to be implemented and modified .

Comment: Thank you so much Sir @kailash Agarwal for giving the code But Sir, here showing a error Please check out the Screenshot https://prnt.sc/pxftqc

Comment: Check the order in which your script references are placed ,first your jquery file will be there then after that jquery ui . U need these two files placed in order to work .